# C++ IDispatch Invoke with output parameter

Tags: com

I am working on an application, which connects to a COM object and calls methods and gets properties from this object etc.
I can connect and call the members, that is not the issue. I cannot however figure out, how to call a method, which has an output parameter, for instance (pseudo code):

```
int GetAppVersion(bsRetMsg [out, optional]).
```

This functions return int as the version and can also return a string representation of the version via the output parameter.

What I've tried:

(1)

```
        VARIANT result;
        DISPPARAMS params = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
        VARIANTARG args[1];

        BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"longerfoostring");
        VariantInit(&args[0]);
        args[0].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
        args[0].bstrVal = str;
        params.rgvarg = args;
        params.cArgs = 1;

        res = dispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &result, NULL,
                               NULL);

        if (SUCCEEDED(res)) {    // here it failed: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
            std::cout << result.intVal << std::endl;
...
```

(2)

```
        VARIANT result;
        DISPPARAMS params = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
        VARIANTARG args[1];

        BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"");    // change: empty string
        VariantInit(&args[0]);
        args[0].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;
        args[0].bstrVal = str;
        params.rgvarg = args;
        params.cArgs = 1;

        res = dispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &result, NULL,
                               NULL);

        if (SUCCEEDED(res)) {    // here it failed: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
            std::cout << result.intVal << std::endl;
...
```

(3)

```
...
BSTR str = SysAllocString(L"longerfoostring");
VariantInit(&args[0]);
args[0].vt = VT_BSTR;    // change: no BYREF
args[0].bstrVal = str;
params.rgvarg = args;
params.cArgs = 1;
... invoke is the same...
res = dispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, &result, NULL,
                               NULL);
if (SUCCEEDED(res)) {
    std::cout << result.intVal << std::endl;    // this number is correct - version in int
    printf("'%S'", params.rgvarg[0].bstrVal);    // prints 'longerfoostring' instead of version, ie. '2.0.5...'
```

(4)

```
BSTR *str;
VariantInit(&args[0]);
args[0].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_PTR;    // change:  different VT
args[0].pbstrVal = str;    //change: different type
params.rgvarg = args;
params.cArgs = 1;
... invoke failes with Bad variable type.
```

So the question is:
How to pass a string (or any type) as an input/output parameter to a COM method and correctly get the output from this parameter?

Comment: That declaration makes very little sense, do post real code instead of "pseudo" code.  Ask the author for the actual declaration in his IDL.  While you are on the phone, ask him to do it right with [in, out, optional]. Best guess is VT_BSTR|VT_BYREF, that requires setting pbstrVal (not bstrVal) to point to a BSTR variable (not BSTR*) that is initialized to NULL.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i asked the dll developer for precise info and the function was:
    HRESULT GetAppVersion([out, optional] VARIANT* bsRetMsg, [out, retval] VARIANT* pVer);
so I used
    VARIANT *retVar = new VARIANT;
    VariantInit(retVar);
    v.pvarVal = retVar;
    v.vt = VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF;

and it worked really nice
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to get back the data, you have to provide the address of a BSTR

```
BSTR str;
VariantInit(&args[0]);
args[0].vt = VT_BSTR | VT_BYREF;    // it's a BSTR and it's by ref
args[0].pbstrVal = &str;    // give address of variable
params.rgvarg = args;
params.cArgs = 1;
```

now call invoke and don't forget to free the returned BSTR.